# Não selecionar, dinamicamente, sempre o último li na hierarquia

Tags: css, css3

Observem o HTML e o CSS abaixo.

Esse é o CSS inicial

```
ul ul li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: #ff0000;
}

<ul>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
      <li>bla bla
        <ul>
          <li>bla bla bla</li>
          <li>Gostaria que não fosse selecionado</li>
          <li>bla bla bla</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Selecionado</li>
      <li>bla bla</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla
    <ul>
        <li>Selecionado</li>
        <li>bla bla</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>bla</li>
</ul>
```

A solução manual seria fazer isso

```
ul ul ul li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: initial;
}
```

Mas não queria fazer assim. Supondo que se eu acrescentasse ao `ul` mais profundo na hierarquia o `li` abaixo.

```
<li>
  bla bla bla
  <ul>
    <li>Agora esse não deve mais ser selecionado</li>
    <li>Bla bla bla bla</li>
  </ul>
</li>

ul ul ul ul li:nth-last-of-type(2){
  background: initial;
}
```

Ou seja, esse CSS não é sustentável. A cada novo nó no `ul` mais profundo terei de dar manutenção no CSS toda vez, acrescentando um novo `ul` na hierarquia para reiniciar a propriedade. Como faço para ele ficar dinâmico?

Comment: Que tal adicionar uma classe nesses `li` diferentes?

Comment: Ia comentar o que o @Lucas disse

Comment: Qual o critério para saber qual deles vai ser o diferente? Talvez seja interessante detalhar o objetivo final, além da forma que está tentando fazer, para não cair num **[Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/)**.

Comment: Então pessoal, o critério eu tentei informar na descrição. Sempre o li mais profundo na hierarquia não deverá ser selecionado. Se eu adicionar no HTML, não quero precisar mexer no CSS. Entende?

Answer (score 1):

E se você fizesse algo assim?

```
li > ul > li {
    background: #ff0000;
}

li > ul > li:first-child,
li > ul > li:last-child {
    background: initial;
}
```

Comment: Vou testar e informo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Use seletores 'id' ou 'class'

## html

```
<li class="lista1">
</li>
```

ou

```
<li id="lista2">
</li>
```

## css

```
.lista1 {color:blue}
'#lista2 {color:green}
```

Toda vez que você identificar uma tag com esses seletores ele assumira as propriedades do código no css.

**Vê se ajuda**
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp